# How to return the correspondant date of a Maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `MyTable` like this:

`Date        Qty     Price
2017-07-01    2       5.00
2017-07-08    3       4.00
2017-08-08    1       6.00`

If I do a query to get the Maximum total cost like this:

`SELECT max(Qty * Price) FROM MyTable`

I get `12.00` which is correct.

How can I have the corresponding Date which is 2017-07-08?
In case of several equal Maximum values, I would like to have the smallest (oldest) date.

Comment: what if you have two equals max values? should show the two?

Comment: I would like to have the smallest date (oldest)

Comment: So, add that info on your question as it can change how we answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table MyTable (date datetime, qty int, price int)

go
insert into MyTable(date,qty,price)
values 
('2017-07-01',    2,       5.00),
('2017-07-08',    3,       4.00),
('2017-08-08',    1,       6.00);

with q as 
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by qty*price desc) rn
  from MyTable
)
select date, qty, price
from q
where rn = 1;
```

outputs

```
date                    qty         price
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2017-07-08 00:00:00.000 3           4

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly one row with max  Qty * Price, oldest day

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY  Qty * Price  DESC, [Date];
```

If you need all the rows with the same max Qty * Price value

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY  Qty * Price  DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it...

```
SELECT 
    [Date]  = CAST(SUBSTRING(mv.MaxBin, 9, 8) AS DATE),
    Qty     = CAST(SUBSTRING(mv.MaxBin, 17, 4) AS INT),
    Price   = CAST(SUBSTRING(mv.MaxBin, 21, 8) AS MONEY)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MaxBin = MAX(CAST(td.Qty * td.Price AS BINARY(8)) + CAST(td.Date AS BINARY(8)) + CAST(td.Qty AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(td.Price AS BINARY(8)))
    FROM
        #TestData td
    ) mv;
```

Edit: How and why this works...

> As you notes in the opening post, “SELECT max(Qty * Price) FROM MyTable” gets you the correct value but that doesn’t help you get the remaining columns from that row.
>
> So the idea is to do the calculation, and then concatenate the other column values to the calculated results so that we can get all the desired columns using the previous logic [MAX(Qty * Price).
>
> Casting things to fixed length binary values allows us to do just that. We know that Qty * Price = ToalPrice or in terms of data types INT * MONEY = MONEY, which is an 8 byte data type… So I know that I can cast any $ amount as a BINARY(8) and know 1) that I’ll always be able to convert it back to money later, 2) the binary value is EXACTLY 8 characters long and 3) I can sort the binary as I would the original value.
>
> Same goes for Date which is a date data type which is 3 bytes long (Yea, I used 8 instead of 3… I’m used to the DATETIME type… my bad on that one)… and so on, with the other columns.
>
> So, by concatenating the binary values together, I can table the MAX of those values, just like you did with max(Qty * Price) but now I have the entire row of data. Now all that has to be done if break the concatenated binary value back into its constituent parts (which is easy because we know exactly how long each section is) using the SUBSTRING function and the cast them back into their original data types.

Comment: That works too, I'm afraid I don't grasp why though. The MaxBin remains uncertain to me. Would that be faster than the previous solutions on a large amount of data?

Comment: My previous answer has been updated with a brief explanation. As far as it being faster than the other methods... It should certainly hold it's own against other single table solutions but indexing will have a huge impact. The only way to know for certain, which i going to be fastest, is to test it in your own environment.